# No "Are you sure you want to delete this file?" message?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, delete, trash

One thing I really hate about Ubuntu is how easy it is to accidentally delete files.

Is there any way to show a pop-up confirmation dialog when the Delete key is pressed, before a file is actually moved to the trash?

Comment: It does ask if you Shift-Delete something (permanently). It's only reversible deletes that are not queried.

Answer (score 2):

### Graphical

Nautilus there is. Right click a file and move it to trash or deleting files.

[image]

### Command line

The command line add a few aliases in ~/.bashrc

```
# Command line
nano ~/.bashrc

# Graphical
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add a few aliases and activate noclobber

```
alias mv='mv -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias rm='rm -i'

set -o noclobber # Override >|
```

No clobber prevents you from redirecting and overwriting to an existing file.

So `echo 'add this' > file` not over write a file if it exists. You can still append `echo 'add this' >> file`. You can over ride it by adding a "|" `echo 'add this' >| file`

### Delete key

I do not know any way of over riding the delete key. You may be able to map the delete key to a script, but, as I would assume you would use the delete key for other tasks, you would then map a key combination to perhaps a zenity script.

Perhaps someone else will add a way to over ride the delete key.

Comment: The *entire question* is about confirmations when accidentally pressing the Delete key though...

Comment: You're going in the wrong direction, bodhi. The OP wants a way to add an *extra* confirmation message to stop things automatically going to the trash. Not remove confirmations.

Comment: I think I posted too fast, updated. @Oli - do you know an easy way to add the desired function to the delete key ?

Answer (score 1):

The lack of an option for this is a result of the Gnome philosophy of striving for simplicity at the expense of easy customisation.

I would recommend switching to another file manager which has this option, like Dolphin or Thunar.

[image]

The default file manager is also difficult to configure in Gnome, but there are [instructions to do so](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager#Changing_Your_Default_File_Manager) on the Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: Thunar does not have this feature anymore.